# Method "codigoActividad" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist add.html.twig

Tags: forms, symfony

Hello I'm trying to show a field from `FormType`, the field is on it, and in the Entity too, but I get the error anyway.

> Method codigoActividad for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"
>   does not exist in
>   AgcBackendBundle:Forms:edit-form-config-actividad.html.twig at line 95

I call to de createForm:

```
$form['form'] = $formulario->createView();
```

the line 95 of the template is..

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ form_widget(form.form.codigoActividad, { 'attr': {'class' : 'form-control','style': 'font-size:11px;'} }) }} </div>
```

and the builder is...

```
$builder
            ->add('nombreActividad',null,array('required' => true))
            ->add('codigoActividad','text')
```

....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strange way how you are rendering both forms... Maybe you could try to create them seperately and just assign a name when you pass to the twig:

```
$formBuilderOne = $this->container
                ->get('form.factory')
                ->createNamedBuilder('formOne', 'form', NULL, array('validation_groups' => array()))
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('submit', 'submit');

        // get form from form builder
        $formOne = $formBuilderOne
                ->getForm()
                ->handleRequest($request);

        // build form
        $formBuilderTwo = $this->container
                ->get('form.factory')
                ->createNamedBuilder('formTwo', 'form', NULL, array('validation_groups' => array()))
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('submit', 'submit');

    // get form from form builder
    $formTwo = $formBuilderTwo
            ->getForm()
            ->handleRequest($request);

    return array(
        'formOne' => $formOne->createView(),
        'formTwo' => $formTwo->createView()
    );
```

Or something like this if you are using form classes:

```
    $formOne = $this->createForm(new FormOneType);

    $formTwo = $this->createForm(new FormTwoType);
```

So in the twig you wont need to do something like `form.form.something`(dont even know if that works). Then you do something like this:

```
{{ form_widget(formOne.codigoActividad) }}
```

Comment: I have problems only with the field codigoActividad, the rest of fields, are shown without problems. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

form.form. it's so strange no ?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ form_widget(form.form.codigoActividad, { 'attr': {'class' : 'form-control','style': 'font-size:11px;'} }) }} </div>
```

try this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ form_widget(form.codigoActividad, { 'attr': {'class' : 'form-control','style': 'font-size:11px;'} }) }} </div>
```

Comment: i have 2 forms, because i have this syntax $form['form'] = $formulario->createView();